# How to absolutely position a child view globally

Tags: swiftui

How do I absolutely position a child view within the main window?

`position(x:y:)` and `offset(x:y:)` are relative to the parent.

The best I got to was to use `GeometryReader` and calculate the position/offset, for example, to position the circle at the bottom of the screen:

```
GeometryReader { geo in
  Circle()
    .foregroundColor(.red)
    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
    .offset(x: 0, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height - geo.frame(in: .global).maxY)
}
```

But it's problematic. `GeometryReader` distorts the layout and the result would change depending on the parent of `Circle`.

Is there a well established way to position Circle, say in the middle of the width of the screen and 10% (or fixed amount) off of the bottom of the screen?

**EDIT:**
here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
struct InnerView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .foregroundColor(.green)
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        LazyVGrid(columns: [.init(),.init()], content: {
            InnerView()
            InnerView()
            InnerView()
        })
    }
}
```

Can one of the `InnerView`s render their circle relative in the mid-bottom area of the window?

Comment: It is not clear how this circle relates (or should relate) to other views on screen or in hierarchy. Would you provide standalone demo code?

Comment: @Asperi, my question is actually about whether it's possible to position the circle relative to the screen regardless of where it's created in the view hierarchy, if that makes sense

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but it depends on other hierarchy because managed view just can become invisible due to overlaps by other views.

Comment: @Asperi, see edit, which hopefully conveys a bit more info

Comment: @Asperi, any suggestions on where to start? I can't seem to find a way of translating the Circle view position in the coordinates of another view with the idea of offsetting it the same amount. `geo.frame(in: .named("other")).minY` doesn't seem to give the value I would have expected. I might be approaching it all wrong

Comment: Did you ever figure this out @NewDev?